# Is there any alternative for any_type in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I am working with both MySQL 5.6 and 5.7. I don't want to turn off only_full_group_by mode but I want the following query to work on both the versions.

SELECT grantee,any_value(count(privilege_type)) FROM information_schema.user_privileges group by grantee;

All I want to know is number of privileges assigned to each user existing in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query without [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value):

```
SELECT grantee, count(privilege_type) 
FROM information_schema.user_privileges 
GROUP BY grantee;
```

You need [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) only on nonaggregated columns. But you are using `COUNT` on the `privilege_type` so the column is aggregated ([list of aggregate functions on MySQL 5.6+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html)). The column `grantee` doesn't need a aggregate function because it is part of the `GROUP BY`.

---

In case you need an alternative for the `ANY_VALUE` function on MySQL 5.6, you can use `MIN` or `MAX` instead.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Pretty new to SQL